# Storing Image in Project Solution and Uploading using Selenium Webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am working on an Automation Project using Selenium Webdriver in VS C#.
I am trying to store Images in the project solution and then call the Path to upload the image to a website. This will make it easier for other Team members to run the tests from their local machines.

I have the below code but it gives an error saying that it cannot find the Image.

This is the Path output and Code:

```
C:\\Users\\john\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3e26bfe4-d723-4776-8379-6ee735dd7b54\\3e26bfe4-d723-4776-8379-6ee735dd7b54\\assembly\\dl3\\5db5fd6a\\c32616d5_bfd0d301\\GoodPhoto.jpg
```

```cs
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string filePath = Path.Combine(folder, "GoodPhoto.jpg");

SendKeys.SendWait(@filePath);
SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

Comment: Are you running everything on your local machine? Or are we talking about a deployed app and a separate selenium server?

Comment: yes running it on my local Machine but stored on tfs. then later on others may download this from tfs and run it on there local machine. Let me know if there's any other info you need

Comment: What testframework do you use to run your selenium tests?

Comment: Thanks Guys but i got a fix 

            'string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(folder, "Framework\\4_Images\\GoodPhoto.jpg");
            string image_path = new Uri(filePath).LocalPath;
            SendKeys.SendWait(image_path);
            SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");'

Comment: Please provide an answer to your question, and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys got a fix for this:

I wasn't Calling the last line "string image_path = new uri" and i was using Location instead of CodeBase.

```
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase); 
string filePath = Path.Combine(folder, "Framework\\4_Images\\GoodPhoto.jpg");
string image_path = new Uri(filePath).LocalPath; 
SendKeys.SendWait(image_path); 
SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```